# Using Python how could I get still image from a certain point in video at a url?

Tags: python, video, web-scraping

Question is basically as the title states. I figure this falls under the domain of webscaping.

Say i wanted to get a .jpg from the frame that occurs in a video at time 0:30. The psuedocode for what I image is this:

1. Generate data from url the video is at.
2. Lookup the 0:30 mark in the video at the url
3. Somehow take a photo of this frame at this time in the video

I am really not sure how to approach this and googling around/search stack overflow is not bringing up any results. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using OpenCV in python

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
```

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get

```
cv.GetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
```